# Move project from Tomcat localhost to "real" server

Tags: java, html, servlets

Ive been developing a Web-project with Java as backend, ive been using Tomcat to host the server. How do I move the project from my local "localhost" to the real external server?

Comment: you can use aws [elastic beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html)

Comment: There are many way. Maybe your IDE can be set to upload to a server. The most common method is via FTP using cuteFTP app (this is only one of many ftp apps available).

Comment: you can check this out it uses joomla but it all depends on the project and server https://docs.joomla.org/Copying_a_website_from_localhost_to_a_remote_host

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need a server with a static IP. It can be VDS/VPS or cloud like AWS.

Then you install and configure Tomcat at the server of your choice.

Then you deploy your app. I can think of a few ways: manually upload app to your remote server via FTP, deploy app to your remote server using IDE tools, push your app to remote Git repository and pull it on your server.
Hope it helps.